# Running PyQGIS script in pycharm?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, pycharm

I did this script in Pycharm and I don't know why python show me this wrong:

**QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::raiseError( QString ) to QgsVectorLayer::raiseError( QString )**

My script below:

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr
from qgis.core import  *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/lib/", True) # Adjust prefix path according to your installation (see note below)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

rootdir = '/media/dogosousa/56A22ED6A22EBA7F/Geoprocessamento/BASE DE DADOS/3.1_SHP/'
extensions = ('.shp')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
        #Print all files which have .shp extension
        if ext in extensions:
            print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
        #Select only one file
        if file == 'leste_otobacia_2015.shp':
            print "#############"
            print file
            # Bringing shape file fileds
            daShapefile = (os.path.join(subdir, file))

            dataSource = ogr.Open(daShapefile)
            daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
            layerDefinition = daLayer.GetLayerDefn()

            field = []
            for i in range(layerDefinition.GetFieldCount()):
                print layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName()
                field.append(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
            field


        if file == 'leste_otobacia_2015.shp':
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(rootdir, str(file), "ogr")

            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('cobacia')
            values = layer.uniqueValues(idx)

            if not layer.isValid():
                print "Layer failed to load!"

                #break
```

Comment: Sidenote: don't force unrequired type conversions on strings (like `str(file)` if you know that file is a string already). This will make your code more compatible with unicode folder names and strings in general.

Answer (score 1):

Need to include filename with root as below:

```
 if file == 'leste_otobacia_2015.shp':
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(os.path.join(rootdir, file), str(file), "ogr")
```

Reference:
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

Comment: Better use `os.path.join(rootdir, file)`